# Difference between launching an app from application list and from installer menu "open"

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am a newbie to android.
I am facing an peculiar issue regarding app relaunch.

Steps :
1) Install the application.
2) Open application from installer launch menu "Open"
3) Minimize the application and open the application from application list.

Result:
One  more application instance is getting created.